# Somando colunas selecionadas

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Eu tenho o seguinte cenário:

Uma tabela criada no razor com várias colunas, onde cada linha tem um checkbox em lugar diferente uns dos outros, e gostaria de fazer a soma de checkbox clicados por coluna via javascript, porem eu não tenho idéia de por onde começar. Alguém poderia ajudar ?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: left;    
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Cell that spans two columns:</h2>

<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>TESTES</th>
    <th colspan="8">PROBLEMAS</th>
    
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>PROB 1</td>
    <td>PROB 2</td>
    <td>PROB 3</td>
    <td>PROB 4</td>
    <td>PROB 5</td>
    <td>PROB 6</td>
    
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>TESTE 1</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="ch[]" value="1" /></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="ch[]" value="1" /></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>TESTE 2</td>    
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="ch[]" value="1" /></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="ch[]" value="1" /></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>TESTE 3</td>    
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="ch[]" value="1" /></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>TESTE 4</td>        
    <td></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="ch[]" value="1" /></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="ch[]" value="1" /></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="ch[]" value="1" /></td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>Resultados</td>        
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  
</table>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Precisa de algumas melhorias, mas o algorítimo pode ficar assim

OBS: como a coluna 0 é a descrição, o valor de `resultadoCheckboxes[0]` será sempre 0;

[Aqui](http://jsfiddle.net/jbn9qL1e/) tem um exemplo (eu coloquei dentro de um timeOut pra dar tempo de você selecionar os checkboxes antes de ele dar um `console.log` em cada valor de `resultadoCheckboxes`)

```
var linhas = document.querySelectorAll('table tr');
var resultadoCheckboxes = [];
for(var indexLinha = 0, numeroLinhas = linhas.length; 
        indexLinha < numeroLinhas; indexLinha++){
   var colunas = linhas[indexLinha].querySelectorAll('td');
   for(var indexColuna = 0, numeroColunas = colunas.length; 
           indexColuna < numeroColunas; indexColuna++){
       var elemento = colunas[indexColuna].querySelector('input[type=checkbox]')
       if(!resultadoCheckboxes [indexColuna]) resultadoCheckboxes [indexColuna] = 0;
       if(elemento && elemento.checked) {
           resultadoCheckboxes [indexColuna] = resultadoCheckboxes [indexColuna] + 1;
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: eu praticamente não tenho muita ideia de javascript, na verdade o problema não é entender o que foi escrito pra mim esta bem claro, mas sim as funcionalidades do javascript, na qual não tenho muita proximidade. Olhando para o seu codigo eu teria que implementar no fim desse codigo um for lendo o array resultadoCheckBoxes e incluir em cada coluna o valor respectivo ao resultado dos dados certo ?

Comment: ao final o `resultadoCheckboxes` já terá a soma de cada coluna (isso é, `resultadoCheckboxes[1]` terá a soma da coluna 1 e assim por diante)

Comment: foi o que eu imaginei, muito obrigado @paulojean